ssh connection on Ubuntu via WSL2 while connected to Windows 10 VPN
To access a supercomputer, I need to connect to the VPN and then perform an ssh command.
Is there a possibility to connect to the VPN via Windows 10 (Cisco VPN Client) and perform the ssh command on Ubuntu via WSL2? If yes, how could I do this?
Thanks.
